# What do you call these labels on the left of org-agenda (filenames)?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm trying to rename these "entries" on the left in my org-agenda view, but not sure what they are called, so not sure how to search for them. Could anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Right now they reflect file names from where each corresponding TODO task comes from. I want to keep the file name the same (`todo.org`), but show them differently in org-agenda (e.g. `orgzly`).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those're categories, you can set them by putting a CATEGORY property under your desired headlines, for example:

```
** Project Foo
:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY: foo
:END:
*** TODO task 1
*** TODO task 2
```

And the agenda format is specified by `org-agenda-prefix-format`, you can also take a look at its docs.